# changed my package name, updated the googleservices.json file, billing and payment stops working

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-play-services

please be lenient, im a newbie here. 
so here is my google-services.json file 
 so once I change my package name and the google-services.json to "com.oldapp.app" the billing works fine but as soon as I change it to the "com.NewApp.app" package name and update to  the new google-services.json it stops working, can anyone please help me fix this? thanks in advance!

````
    {
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "12144",
    "firebase_url": "https://oldapp-123.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "oldapp-123",
    "storage_bucket": "oldapp-123.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "123",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.oldapp.app"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "123.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.oldapp.app",
            "certificate_hash": "d123"
          }
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "awdqwd"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "1234s.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            },
            {
              "client_id": "9123h.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 2,
              "ios_info": {
                "bundle_id": "com.oldapp.app"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1237:android:123",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.oldapp.app.dev"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "sadad"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "9132as.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            },
            {
              "client_id": "1412ded.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 2,
              "ios_info": {
                "bundle_id": "com.oldapp.app"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "112123:android:csees",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.oldapp02.app"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "asdasd"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "adwad4s.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            },
            {
              "client_id": "adawawd.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 2,
              "ios_info": {
                "bundle_id": "com.oldapp.app"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:234234:android:c1qadad416ee6",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.NewApp.app"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "asdadagj.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.NewApp.app",
            "certificate_hash": "asadasd"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "asadadsf.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.NewApp.app",
            "certificate_hash": "sdfsfsf"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "24234243.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.NewApp.app",
            "certificate_hash": "afadsd"
          }
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "zdfzs"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "sfsfefsv7qi4s.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            },
            {
              "client_id": "asadasdnth.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 2,
              "ios_info": {
                "bundle_id": "com.oldapp.app"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}






and this is the old google-services.json file for the old package 

   ``` {
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "1231244",
    "firebase_url": "https://oldapp-34d.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "oldapp-74d",
    "storage_bucket": "oldapp-3d.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "12414141275",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.oldapp.app"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "124124124214m.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.oldapp.app",
            "certificate_hash": "fadadad"
          }
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "sfasdadas"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "9sdfafa23423s.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            },
            {
              "client_id": "92asfsfasasfsah.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 2,
              "ios_info": {
                "bundle_id": "com.oldapp.app"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "asdasdasdf",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.oldapp.app.dev"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "asdsadads"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "sdasdsads.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            },
            {
              "client_id": "asdadadadsh.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 2,
              "ios_info": {
                "bundle_id": "com.oldapp.app"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours of breaking my head, I realized I didn't add the products to the new package, after adding the products in the play console everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported to change the package name (application ID) of an app without also adding a new app to the Firebase project in the console. [Register a new app in the console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#register-app), then delete the old one. As the linked documentation says:

> Make sure that you enter the package name that your app is actually using. You cannot add or modify this value after you register your app with your Firebase project.

Comment: well, i did register a new app on the firebase console, and i used that apps service file in my project. it doesnt  seem to solve the issue